# Python Flask app with arguments

Tags: python, flask

I have written a basic web server in Python which could accept some arguments, e.g.

```
python server.py -m
```

Because it was turning out to be complicated, I decided to switch to Flask which is run by first exporting the path to the .py file, as follows:

```
export FLASK_APP=server.py
flask run
```

But this won't allow me to use arguments anymore. How to work around it?

Only way I see now is making a different .py file for each argument option but that seems so bad.

Comment: What do the arguments do? Could you not use environment variables?

Comment: @DanielRoseman `-m` sets whether to use `:memory:` for the sqlite DB or not; this is the option I care most about. The other was to specify port but flask has that; however, what if I had more? Nevertheless, (how) could one use an environment variable to solve the `-m` memory option?

Comment: The same way you use the command line argument, surely? Why does it make a difference where the value comes from?

Comment: flask-script sounds a option if you thinking to have more than one option. http://flask-script.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. or click:  http://click.pocoo.org/6/